# Acceleration of an air bubble under the sea

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

An air bubble arises from the bottom of the sea. Find its acceleration if the resistance force is proportional to $\rho$*A*$v$ where $\rho$ is density of water, A is cross section area and $v$ is velocity of the bubble. Density and temperature of water are constant.

There was also a part a) of this exercise, where there was no resistance force, and i used Newton's law:

$$ma=\rho Vg -mg$$

and

$$pV=nRT$$

and obtained $a= g(\dfrac{\rho RT}{M(p_a+\rho gh)}-1)$, which means acceleration depends only of the depth $h$. But in the case with the resistance force I write:

$$ma=\rho Vg -mg-k\rho Av$$

and after I plug in $a=\frac{dv}{dt}$ and solve the differential equation i get

$$a=\dfrac{e^{\dfrac{-t}{p_a+\rho gh}}}{M(p_a+\rho gh)kART}$$

So, my question is, can I have $t$ and A in the final solution, am I doing this correct? Every advice would be helpful

Comment: You can't solve this exercise as the value of the cross-section is unknown. (You can't relate it to the volume as the height of the bubble is unknown.) Anyway, a negative exponential is the typical behavior for viscous friction, but you didn't account for the fact that $v=dh/dt$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes, I'm aware of that, but from the exercise statement I can't clearly conclude if I should use A as a known figure. Occurence of $t$ in the final solution is ok? I did use $v=dh/dt$ in the first case.

Comment: I don't think so. How did you solve the differential equation ?

Comment: First I've expressed $m=\dfrac{MV(p_a+\rho gh)}{RT}$, and then wrote

$$\dfrac{dv}{dt}=\dfrac{\rho gRT - gM(p_a+\rho gh) - kv\ rho ART}{M(p_a+\rho gh)}$$

$$\dfrac{dv}{\rho gRT - gM(p_a+\rho gh) - kv\ rho ART}={dt}{M(p_a+\rho gh)}$$

and solved by substitution $z=\rho gRT - gM(p_a+\rho gh) - kv\ rho ART$, $dz=-k \rho ARTdv$ to get $v$ and then differentieted a=\dfrac{dv}{dt}$

Comment: Your expression of $dz$ is wrong, you forgot the term with $dh$. Actually about everything is wrong, you must write a second order equation in terms of $h$.

Comment: And how do I do that? I'm sorry, I haven't had any course in differential equations, so I'm doing some things I pick up online

Comment: Write everything in terms of $h$ and its derivatives. You'll probably get a monster that can't be solved.

Comment: I've also tried different approach, by writing $a=\dfrac{dv}{dt}$ and $v=\dfrac{dh}{dt}$ in the initial equation and then multiplying both sides with $dt$. I got

$$ dv=\dfrac{(\rho gRT -gM(p_a+ \rho gh)) dt}{M(p_a+ \rho gh)} - \dfrac{k \rho ART dh}{M(p_a+ \rho gh)}$$ but I don't know how to solve this

Comment: That's the monster. Write it in the form of $a(h)h''+b(h)h'+c(h)h=d(h)$ (and regroup the constants for clarity).

Comment: I know I can write dv as the second derivative of h with respect to t, but how can I get rid of this dt on the right hand side?

Comment: Just divide by $dt$.

Comment: but don't I go back where I started?

Comment: Write the equation like I said.

Comment: So, if I'm correct, the equation looks like:

$$ M(p_a+ \rho gh)h'' + k \rho ART h' + gM(p_a+ \rho gh)= \rho gRT$$

What next?

Comment: This is not exactly the requested form. And please regroup those constants. The theory tells you to look for the general solution of the homogeneous equation (RHS=0). And now I have no idea what to do, because all coefficients are constant, except for the term $hh''$.

Comment: In what way should I regroup them? I'm sorry once again, but this is really the first time I'm encountering differential equations.

Comment: Nothing to do with differential equations: $gM\rho kp_a\cdots$ is adding noise.

Comment: I honestly don't know what you mean by this adding noise? This is really confusing for me

Comment: Aren't you tired of typing all these constants ?

Comment: Now you need to read about "second order linear differential equation with nonconstant coefficients".

Comment: Well, I just copy them...and I don't won't to forget them later, because they are important in this exercise

Answer (score 0):

I think the same as the other person who replied to you.
You cannot solve this exercise since the value of the cross section is unknown. (You can't relate it to volume since the height of the bubble is unknown.) Anyway, a negative exponential is the typical behavior of viscous friction, but it didn't take into account the fact that v = reh / dt.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).